# Invalid argument in PHP form - foreach()

Tags: php, forms, foreach, warnings

I keep getting a "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 102" message when I test my PHP contact form. I have rebuilt my website recently, but I am using the exact same PHP contact form code that I used on my old website, and the old website's form still works without error. I have copied & pasted it word for word, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. Any help would really be appreciated.

Here is the line that I am getting the supposed error on (line 102):

```
foreach($errors as $value) {
```

Here is the entire form script (the error line is right at the bottom):

```
<?php 

// 
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{

    //This is checking if the string length in the firstname field was greater than 1 character
    if(strlen($_POST["firstname"]) > 1)
    {

        $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
        //echo $firstname;
    }

    else
    {
        //echo "You did not type in first name";
        $errors["firstname"] = "<span class=\"error\">You did not type in a first name.</span>";
    }


    if(strlen($_POST["lastname"]) > 1)
    {

        $lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
    }

    else
    {
        $errors["lastname"] = "<span class=\"error\">You did not type in a last name.</span>";
    }


    if(strlen($_POST["email"]) > 1)
    {

        $email = $_POST["email"];

        if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $email = $email;
        }

        else {
            $errors["email"] = "<span class=\"error\">Email is invalid.</span>";
        }
    }

    else
    {
        $errors["email"] = "<span class=\"error\">You did not type in an email address.</span>";
    }

    //This is checking if the string length in the message field was greater than 1 character
    if(strlen($_POST["message"]) > 1)
    {

        $message = $_POST["message"];
        //echo $firstname;
    }

    else
    {

        $errors["message"] = "<span class=\"error\">You did not type in a message.</span>";
    }


    // Code to tell form NOT to send form if there are any errors.
    if($errors < 1)
    {
            $to = "example@email.com";
            $from = $email;
            // headers makes sure you have a reply-to address
            $headers = "From: {$from}" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';

            $subject =  
                "From: ($from)" . "<br />" .
                "First name: ($firstname)" . "<br />" .
                "Last name: ($lastname)" . "<br />" .
                "Email: ($email)" . "<br />" .
                "Message: ($message)";

            if(mail($to, $from, $subject, $headers))
            {
                $finalMsg = "<p class=\"success\">Thank you! Your email was sent.</p>";
            }

            else {
                $finalMsg = "<p class=\"error\">Your email was NOT sent. Please try again.</p>";
            }

}

?>

<?php

//each error is displayed

foreach($errors as $value) {

echo "<span>$value</span><br />";

}
    }
?>
```

Comment: Is the wording of the warning message not clear enough? `foreach` expects something array-ish, and it didn't get one. You probably didn't initialize `$errors` to an empty array and it is not defined when there are no validation errors. (Also, `$errors < 1` won't work...)

Comment: Add `$errors = array();` at the top maybe? You're manipulating `$errors` in multiple places, but never telling PHP that it is an array.

Comment: Since you are new here, accept the answer(tick) which solved your problem. Up-vote(up arrow) the answer(s) which give(s) you information or help(s) you. Down-vote(down arrow) the answer(s) which are fake.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 

$errors = array();
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    ...
```

**You have to define all your variables.**
Are you doing it for `$firstname`? So you should have it for `$errors` as well.

Also, do not add formatting when defining errors, add it at output. It will save you a lot of typing.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a foreach on something that is not an array. You should check that what you are passing to `foreach` is an array by using the **[is_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php)** function

If you are not sure it's going to be an array you can always check using the following PHP example code:

```
if (is_array($errors)) {

  foreach ($errors as $error) {
   //do something
  }
}
```

## Note

> The foreach construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays.
>   foreach works only on arrays and objects, and will issue an error when
>   you try to use it on a variable with a different data type or an
>   uninitialized variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `if(is_array($errors))` around your foreach loop.

Take a look at PHP's error_reporting levels: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Most likely your old web server had a lower error reporting level configured.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `$errors` is not set before hand which would cause errors trying to iterate over. As others suggested around the same time as me, declaring `$errors` before hand should fix this particular issue.

Something like `$errors = array();` before your first `if-statement` would do the trick. Otherwise also similar to other people's suggestions, doing `isset` or `is_array` (slightly better due to it checking whether it is an array as well) would help.

[PHP foreach Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down, if `$_POST['submit']` is set and all the other variables he is checking against are correct, the `$errors` object is **never** set in the code, this would cause this issue.